# Django project to domain, vps

Tags: python, django, dns, vps

I have VPS-server (CentOS 6.8)

I installed Python 3.5.2 and Django 1.10.1 on virtual enviroment

I connected my domain to VPS-server

Now:

```
django-project:
(venv) /home/django_user/djtest/venv/django_project/django_project

domain:
/var/www/www-root/data/www/mydomain.com
```

I tried set `BASE_DIR` in settings.py to `'/var/www/www-root/data/www/mydomain.com'` but not working

How I can to connect django-project to domain?

Project is still empty, just created

Answer (score 1):

Django project can't be served like this, you need some web-server application like gunicorn or apache too.

Just like you use `./manage.py runserver` you need some application to execute your django project corresponsing to command theses application are [Gunicorn](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi5l_menqXPAhVD1oMKHT66BHAQFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgunicorn.org%2F&usg=AFQjCNH4886vZhhVrpKRkAak1Ja0k68d3g&sig2=CX1x8Pp8NmDM8DFIXNlMNA), [ApacheWSGI server](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/) and [others](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/).

There will be a file `wsgi.py` that would have created when you created the project it's **web server gateway interface** it will interact with the above mentioned web-servers and server your django based website.